# Calling AJAX function of parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a HTML webpage with a hyperlink. On click of this link same webpage is opened in another window with a hash value appended to the url using `window.open`. Example url `http://mywebsite.com#hash=value`

There is a Javascript function on the webpage that checks for this hash value in the url and calls a Javascript function of parent window as following, if it founds the hash value:

```
// if required hashvalue is in the url
if(hashvalue){
    window.parent.func(hashvalue);
    window.close();
}
```

Following is the function defined on the same webpage:

```
function func(hashvalue){
var turl = 'some url';
    alert(hashvalue)
    jQuery.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: turl,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp : "callback",
    success: function(response) {
    alert(response)
    }, error: function(x, y, z){
    alert(JSON.stringify(x) + "\r\n" + JSON.stringify(y))
    }
});
}
```

Here is what is happening after clicking the link:

Popup window opens with hash value appended to the url. Hash value is being checked, Javascript function `func` is being called, `alert(hashvalue)` alerts and popup window closes. Problem is, the second alert `alert(response)` is not getting called. I have checked the browser console, there is not any error.

If I remove `window.close();` (Popup window is not closed), the second alert `alert(response)` is also getting called.

I want the popup window to be closed and the function `func` to be executed completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not giving your 2nd function enough time to be called before closing the window. You can set the 2nd function within your parent window, with a timeout if you need, in order for it to always be available to act.

Comment: As I mentioned, the popup window is the same webpage where there is the link, so the function is there in the parent window. I think, even after closing the window, function should get called because the function definition is there in the parent window all the time.

Comment: In that case, let the 2nd function close your child window, by simply routing your call to 2nd function with a reference to the window its being called from, hence the window you will close upon finishing the processing of 2nd function.

Comment: I tried this and this is working. But in this case, before AJAX function response is fetched, page content is loaded in the popup window. Can I show blank page (or loading image) till the AJAX response is fetched and then close the window?

Comment: Yep, just set the URL to popup window to whatever you want, blank page or what have you, then upon ajax 'success' or 'complete', populate window with your results.